# TXT->JSON with Yahoo! Pipes

Tags: json, yahoo-pipes

I have a txt file on the web, that is constructed like this:

```
"key1 value1
 key2 value2
 key3 value3
..."
```

Can I using Yahoo! Pipes parse it to JSON? The end format should be like:

```
{key1 : value1, 
 key2 : value2, 
 key3 : value3, 
 ...}
```

Comment: "On 4 June 2015 it was announced that Pipes would be in read-only mode from 30 August 2015, and shut down on 30 September 2015" [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Pipes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Use **Fetch CSV** with space as separator, feed it through a **Loop** with **String Builder** to insert the colons and commas, then another **String Builder** to insert the braces. But beware of the last comma!

Anyway that's the general idea to get you started...